# HTML, SCSS not compiled on save - Angular 11.0.2

Tags: frontend, angular-cli, ivy, angular11, angular-cli-v9

I upgraded my app  to `Angular cli ^11.0.2` recently, from then my **HTML and SCSS changes are not compiled on save** even when `ng serve` is running. I have to save the respective ts file to get the html changes compile. I saw a related issue on **Github** with no proper solution([Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13588)). Is this because of `ivy` engine ? or Did I miss any update on any particular npm package?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to happen due to default Ivy engine configuration with Angular 11.

I disabled the `enableIvy` flag in tsconfig.json file like this :

- `"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false, "allowEmptyCodegenFiles": true }`

A friend suggested that **AOT** with **ivy** configuration must be avoided in dev environment to avoid this kind of issues.